# Open multiple Wordpress projects in the docker

Tags: docker

I am creating containers for all my projects, mostly in Wordpress, and I was wondering if for example I could upload several projects at the same time, because in this configuration that I use the docker, I have to disable one, in order to activate another. Example project1.local and project2.local, how could you do it that way?

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'
services:
    wordpress:
        build: .
        container_name: ${APP_NAME}-wordpress
        restart: always
        ports: 
            - 80:80
        environment: 
            WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: ${DB_HOST}
            WORDPRESS_DB_USER: ${DB_USER}
            WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASS}
            WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: ${DB_NAME}
            WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: ${DB_TABLE_PREFIX}
            WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: |
                /* Direct FTP */
                define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');

        volumes:
            - ./src:/var/www/html/wp-content:rw
            - ./config/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini
        depends_on:
            - db

    db:
        image: mariadb
        container_name: ${APP_NAME}-db
        volumes:
            - './database/db:/var/lib/mysql:delegated'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_NAME}
            MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USER}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASS}
        restart: always
        ports:
            - '3306:3306'

    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        container_name: ${APP_NAME}-phpmyadmin
        volumes:
            - ./config/phpmyadmin.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/phpmyadmin.ini
        environment:
            PMA_HOST: ${DB_HOST}
            PMA_PORT: 3306
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
        ports:
            - '8080:80'
        links:
            - db:db
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM wordpress
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some things that you can do:

1- Since you've declare:

```
ports:
   - 80:80
```

You can't get to many wordpress at the same time with different docker-compose. So, you can delete the binding from your instance like this:

```
ports:
- 80
```

Doing it, you can make several docker-compose with different ports without worrying about the ports.

But there is another problem... Your database it's already up. So, in this case, if you want to use several docker-compose for each project you'll need another docker-compose for your database. So... the docker-compose solution is get another docker-compose for your database and in every docker-compose file add an external network:

With it, you can use the dns name as its always.

The other way is using the same template like this:

```
version: '3.3'
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: wordpresses
services:
    wordpress_1:
        build: .
        container_name: ${APP_NAME}-wordpress
        restart: always
        ports: 
            - 80
        environment: 
            WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: ${DB_HOST}
            WORDPRESS_DB_USER: ${DB_USER}
            WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASS}
            WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: ${DB_NAME}
            WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: ${DB_TABLE_PREFIX}
            WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: |
                /* Direct FTP */
                define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');

        volumes:
            - ./src/project1:/var/www/html/wp-content:rw
            - ./config/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini
        depends_on:
            - db

    wordpress_2:
        build: .
        container_name: ${APP_NAME}-wordpress
        restart: always
        ports: 
            - 80
        environment: 
            WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: ${DB_HOST}
            WORDPRESS_DB_USER: ${DB_USER}
            WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASS}
            WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: ${DB_NAME}
            WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: ${DB_TABLE_PREFIX}
            WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: |
                /* Direct FTP */
                define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');

        volumes:
            - ./src/project2:/var/www/html/wp-content:rw
            - ./config/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini
        depends_on:
            - db

    db:
        image: mariadb
        container_name: ${APP_NAME}-db
        volumes:
            - './database/db:/var/lib/mysql:delegated'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_NAME}
            MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USER}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASS}
        restart: always
        ports:
            - '3306:3306'

    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        container_name: ${APP_NAME}-phpmyadmin
        volumes:
            - ./config/phpmyadmin.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/phpmyadmin.ini
        environment:
            PMA_HOST: ${DB_HOST}
            PMA_PORT: 3306
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
        ports:
            - '8080:80'
        links:
            - db:db
```

I know wordpress has some issues if you don't put the domain. In any case, you can use a NGINX in front of all wordpress as a reverse proxy like this [Example.](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy)

Feel free to ask!